# SAS Macro not detecting a file

Tags: macros, sas

CMS released a SAS macro that checks for the existence of a file:

```
** check existance of dataset**;
%macro CHECKDS(FILE,LONGFILE);
  %if %sysfunc(exist(&FILE)) %then;
  %else %do;
  data _null_;
  file print ls=255;
  &MSG30 put "ERROR  : [Msg30] Program halted, file &LONGFILE does not exist";
  abort; run;
%end;
%mend CHECKDS;
```

Now when I call it with this:

```
LIBNAME  IN1     "/folders/myfolders/";
%CHECKDS(&STPERSON.TXT,PERSON)
run;
```

I get this error: ERROR  : [Msg30] Program halted, file PERSON does not exist.

I know that the files exists and is in that location. Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like a problem with your macro resolution. Change the `&STPERSON.TXT` to `&STPERSON..TXT`, which will allow your macro variable to resolve, but leave a period character between that and the extension (TXT).

Comment: I actually simplified this from the true setup. The macro that is calling CHECKDS() is passing it a variable 'INP' that is assigned in a different macro. So its actually: %CHECKDS(&INP, PERSON). But I'm trying to explicitly call if with the actual file for testing. Neither one works. Your suggestion above did not work, but thanks,

Comment: For testing purposes, add `%put &FILE;` below the `%macro` statement. This will allow you to see exactly what the `exist` function is looking for.

Comment: SAS UE is case sensitive, is the file PERSON or person? and most likely it would .txt not TXT

Comment: No That is exactly how it is appearing in the left hand pane...all caps including the .TXT. But I tried lower case .txt and still didn't work.

Comment: Just realised that `EXIST` is the function for checking for a dataset. Have you tried `FILEEXIST` instead?

Comment: @mjsqu I think you're right. OP wants to check for the existence of a file that is not necessarily a dataset or other library member.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument to the `exist` function should be in the format `libname.memname`. The second argument to the `exist` function specifies the member type; since you didn't specify the member type, the default, DATA, is assumed. This implies a file with a SAS data file with a sas7bdat extension.

See [here](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostunx/61879/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000502205.htm) for a list of member types.

Since your file is a .txt file, I don't think it can be considered a library member. Anyone is welcome to correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

DWal got it right above. Here's a more complete answer for what I had to do. I had to convert the .txt file to a sas data set (particularly .sas7bdat).

```
proc import datafile="/folders/myfolders/PERSON"
    dbms=dlm
    out=person
    replace;
    delimiter=' ';
    getnames=yes;
run;
```

Then that had to be written to my library and I was able to use it.

```
data IN1.person ;
set person;
run;
```